# The spring JPA is not able to understand this JSON. What can be the reason?

Tags: json, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Main question is I am not able to POST new data into the database using Ajax or curl.

Error I am facing :

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)):

Contents of Users.java :

```
package com.harmathuwebLogin;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

@Entity
@Table (name="Users")
public class Users {

@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column (name="firstname")
private String firstName;

@Column (name="lastname")
private String lastName;

@Column (name="username")
private String userName;

@Column (name="password")
private String passWord;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassWord() {
    return passWord;
}

public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
    this.passWord = passWord;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String res = "{ \"firstName\" : " + this.firstName + " }";
    return res;
}

}
```

Contents of UsersRepository.java :

```
package com.harmathuwebLogin;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UsersRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Users, Long>{
List<Users> findByLastName (@Param("lastName") String lastName);

boolean findByUserNameAndPassWord(@Param("userName") String userName, @Param("passWord") String passWord);
}
```

Contents of Application.java :

```
package com.harmathuwebLogin;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

ALso,

```
If I try to go to "http://localhost:8080/users", it returns a valid JSON, also it returns correct json with "http://localhost:8080/users/1"
```

The problem is when I try to do

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "firstName" : "Frodo",  "lastName" : "Baggins", "userName" : "frodobaggins", "passWord" : "shireisheaven" }' http://localhost:8080/users
```

It gives :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/schema+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 20 Jul 2014 08:05:53 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "cause" : {
    "cause" : null,
    "message" : "Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): was expecting double-quo
te to start field name\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputSt
ream@7afb3085; line: 1, column: 5]"
  },
  "message" : "Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): was e
xpecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.conn
ector.CoyoteInputStream@7afb3085; line: 1, column: 5]; nested exception is com.f
asterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)):
 was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.apache.catalin
a.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7afb3085; line: 1, column: 5]"
```

It shows this error in Eclipse Console :

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

Comment: What looks suspicious here is that you allegedly get `application/schema+json` for said request, which I can hardly believe. Don't think this has anything to do with the JPA setup but rather with the Jackson integration.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for looking into this. Probably the problem lies in schema/json. I am using Windows Power Shell, I know it's a shame. If you notice my curl command using POST, it's still giving content type as schema + json, instead of just application/json. Also If I remove -H headers from curl, then I face a different issue : 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: No suitable HttpMessageConverter found to read request body into object of type class com.harmathuwebLogin.Users from request with content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just run your code and tested with Google rest client for posting users data.Its working fine. Problem in your case seems to be that some how header content type is ging as 
**Content-Type: application/schema+json instead of Content-Type:application/json**.

Can you use some other rest client instead of curl and verify by setting Content-Type:application/json i the header.

Also Just try the following:

```
Remove import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView; from User model class.
```

Also comment out the following two annotation in repository class:

```
//@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
//@ComponentScan
```

You can check the modified running code from here :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-o8NN2qlp3DRVpUS044UmlmRWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/
If you look at this link, JPA do all that mapping for the developer. And for the example given in that link, They have not used any such annotation for POST or GET. Only Difference in my code is MYSQL instead of h2 database.

Comment: Please check my modified answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I have removed that import and @componentscan annotation, can't remove property source as that has the mysql related parameters. I am still facing same issue, if I don't specify content than also I face different issue

Comment: Hi,Ok, you are right, The code works, it was JSON client that was the issue.